# Who can ask questions on Speak With Dead

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead

When a caster casts Speak With Dead, in DND 5E, do only questions asked by the caster count towards the 5 questions, or are all questions asked within earshot of the corpse applied to the 5 total?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 11):

#### The corpse only answers the caster's questions.

*Speak with dead* states:

> **You** grant the semblance of life and intelligence to a corpse of your choice within range [...]
>
> Until the spell ends, **you** can ask the corpse up to five questions.

"You" here refers to the caster, indicating that the corpse only responds to questions asked by the caster.